# How to search a file in SQL db with a date in filename

Tags: sql, database

Every Monday we receive 6 files from a different application into our SQL database. These files name contain yesterday's date as yyyymmdd format.

Example of file name is [ESMA-20170516_0099112], [ESMA-20170516_0099113],[ESMA-20170516_0099114],[ESMA-20170516_0099115], [ESMA-20170516_0099116],[ESMA-20170516_0099117]

I need to check and see if there are total of 6 files as named above with the yest's date.If any of the above file is missing, a mail should be sent out.

Any ideas on how I can do this.
Thank You.

Comment: do you even know what you are asking?

Comment: You can use the `LIKE` operator.

Comment: Are these files in a table or in the file system?

Comment: which database engine? what is the table name and the column name where the file names are held?

Comment: Please start by trying yourself. If you have a specific problem, show some code and explain where exactly you need our help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming sql server

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtablename WHERE fileNameField LIKE '%-20170516_%'
```

replace the yourtablename and fileNameField with appropriate values and use the correct date you are interested in (pass it in from your code).

Comment: Ok can you also show how to pass date from a batch script?

Comment: that feels like a different question... similar questions to that have been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30838847/pass-parameter-value-to-sql-file-from-batch-file-using-batch-command and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140584/passing-parameters-to-oracle-sql-file-from-batch-file etc. I suggest you do what @friedemann_bach suggested - update the question with the code for the batch script, the sql you are trying to use, which sql database you are using etc. and then people will have more details.

Comment: Hey thank you so much for all your suggestions!! will surely update with the details as you suggested above..I am a total newbie here..getting used to this platform.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
select * from table where filename like %CONCAT(YEAR(GETDATE()),CASE WHEN 
LEN(MONTH(GETDATE())) = 1 THEN '0' ELSE null END, MONTH(GETDATE()), 
DAY(DATEADD(d,-1,GETDATE())))%
```

Comment: This would work, but only on the Monday (so, not on any day after that), and also only if the Monday and the Sunday before it are in the same month (and year).

Comment: The Monday requirement wasn't listed in the question when I posted this answer.

Comment: Fair enough, but it still said "previous day", and this will not work if the previous day is also in the previous month.

Comment: That's true, I should have used MONTH(DATEADD(d,-1,GETDATE())

Comment: probably. and similar for year.